# Android MainActivity does not update fragment Actionbar title on onResume when back button is pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

When an item is pressed in navigation drawer . It creates a new fragment . The title of the actionbar updates. But when i press the back button previous fragment displays But ActionBar title does not changes . .Here is the code for DrawerItemClickListener .

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
         mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        selectItem(position);

    }
}


  private void selectItem(final int position) {

     mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.activity_home, homeFragment,"homeFragment")
                            .commit();
                       setTitle("Home");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ProductFragment productFragment = new ProductFragment();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.activity_home, productFragment,"productFragment")
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                            setTitle("Products");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    BillFragment billFragment = new BillFragment();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.activity_home, billFragment,"billFragment")
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                             setTitle("Bill");
                    break;

            }
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };
mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

I tried the below code to update the title when activity state changes. When back button pressed it always set actionbar Title as defaultTitle . Other conditions does not executed.

```
   @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    HomeFragment homeFragment = (HomeFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("homeFragment");
    ProductFragment productFragment = (ProductFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("productFragment");
    BillFragment billFragment = (BillFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("billFragment");

    if(homeFragment != null && homeFragment.isVisible()) {
        setTitle(getString(R.string.Home));
    }
    else if( productFragment != null && productFragment.isVisible())
    {
        setTitle(getString(R.string.Products));
    }
    else if(billFragment != null && billFragment.isVisible()){
        setTitle(getString(R.string.Bills));
    }
    else {
        setTitle("defaultTitle");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting title on Activity's `onResume()`, get the `ActionBar` instance in fragment and set title there for every fragment

Set the below code in `onCreateView()` or `onResume()` of all fragments

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your title");
```

Comment: It works . But its a complex work . Is there a way to update all fragments name in a single place ? Why findFragmentByTag and isVisible doesn't works ?

Comment: finding fragment and setting it is more complex and expensive that the one above.